# Doctrine 2: reattaching entities through value objects

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, persistence, entitymanager

I'm working with Doctrine 2, and have an `Address` value object:

```php
class Address
{
    /** @var string */
    protected $street;

    /** @var string */
    protected $city;

    /** @var Application\Domain\Model\Country */
    protected $country;
}
```

I need to store this `Address` in a PHP session (serialized), and retrieve it later on. When I then retrieve this value object, I want to have the `Country` object merged to the current Entity Manager, so that this Country is in sync with the current unit of work.

Is it possible to "merge" this value object to the current Entity Manager, as I would do on a regular entity with `cascade="merge"`, to get the `Country` instance replaced with the current one?

I can obviously manually create another `Address` with a manually merged `Country`:

```
$address = $_SESSION['address'];
$country = $em->merge($address->getCountry());
$address = new Address($address->getStreet(), $address->getCity(), $country);
```

But I'm wondering if I'm missing a feature in Doctrine that would allow me to directly merge the VO instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is currently no documented way to do that.

Comment: There is a WIP by the doctrine team for implementing value objects support : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/634

Comment: @YohanG. Yes I've seen that, though it's slightly different from what I'm looking for. But native VO support will be awesome anyway!